# Zero safe area in landscape mode in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, safearealayoutguide, safearea

I have a simple `UIViewController` and just try to add a subview which fullfills all available safe area. The result with xib, storyboard and sometimes programmatically is the same - Xcode ignores safe area in landscape mode:
[image]

The result I expect is approximate the following (side distances to safe area):

[image]

How to achieve such behaviour?

Comment: @iOSDev Xcode shows that all the constraints are between this view and safe area. Additionally I tried to delete leading constraint from xib programmatically and add a new one - again between a view and safe area but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Xcode xibs and storyboards ignore horizontal safe area but apply it later.

The problem of my concrete case is I used `SOPullUpControl` and wanted to customise its container before presenting. The problem is `SOPullUpControl` involves view frames but safe area insets appear after view controller presentation only. So `SOPullUpControl` can be fully initialised when its container is on screen only.